# passing arguments to a c code from java

Tags: java

How can I pass arguments to a C program which takes input from some **inputstreams** 
(like **scanf()**) from a text file which is already saved and i am running the .exe using **Runtime.getRuntime().exec()** in **java.**

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to create a text file with the data to pass? This is one strange question...

Comment: @Fabiotocchi Might be homework.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the C program reading input from a text file it opens itself, or is it reading input from `stdin` and you want the Java program to pass the contents of the text file to it? If the former, is the name of the text file hard coded in the C file or does it expect it as a parameter?

Comment: @millimoose strange homework nowadays...

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exe` allows you to specify the program to execute, along with arguments for the program. Have a look at the [Java API documentation for `exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

```
   String[] command = new String[2];
   command[0] = "c:\\bin\\someProgram.exe";
   command[1] = "c:\\data\\arguments.txt";
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

If the data for the C program is already stored in a file, you should pass the file directly as an argument (This depends, of course, on the exact nature of the program and any pre-processing required -- you'll need to give us details for a better answer).

Comment: This answer is a little light on substance... Also it seems the OP is already as far as to run the program.

Comment: Not much to go on with this kind of question, but I guess the OP might be confused about how to pass arguments -- the documentation of `exec` is not very clear.

Comment: True, but in that case I lean towards asking for clarification and burying the question if none is forthcoming over throwing code snippets at the wall to see which one sticks.

Comment: thanks for your answer @TonythePony i wanted the same thing but will it be able to take values automaticlly even if my c program is not taking command line arguments?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to pass data to your program from a file instead of doing it interactively. You can use I/O redirection for this. In the unix philosophy `everything is a file` and this helps because your input stream `stdin` is also a file.

Let me illustrate this with an example. I'll post a

```
int main(){
  int a, b;
  std::cin >> a >> b;
  std::cout << a+b << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You compile this with something like `g++ sum.cpp` and run this like

```
./a.out 
3 4
```

This prints `7` as you'd expect. But you had to manually enter this data and if this data remains the same then entering this over and over doesn't make sense. Here comes I/O redirection. What we want to do is to tell the program that instead of reading from `stdin`, it should read from another file.

To test this create a simple text file `input.text` with `3 4` as its contents. Now run this program with `./a.out < input.txt` and this will again print `7` if you change the numbers in the file and run the program again you'll get the appropriate result.

So what you're trying to do has got nothing to do with Java or C or scanf or some other way of taking input. As a side note instead of using `Runtime` you should consider using `commons exec`. 
To better understand redirection read [this](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles2/042.html) and [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Note : Since you mention that you want to run `exe` files I assume that you run windows. You may need to change `a.out` to `a.exe` or whatever name your ide compiles it into. Hope it helps feel free to let me know if I didn't explain something clearly.

Comment: thanks nikhil for the answer but this is not exactly i wanted
still i got answer using input/output redirection
thanks for that as well